# psycopg2 cannot be installed with docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, psycopg2

I am developing an application using djangorestframework and postgresql database. Firstly I have used alpine:python3.8 image and everything was working including psycopg2. Then, I need to use machine learning packages. I could not install scipy,matplotlib,catsim etc. with alpine:python3.8 image.

So I have changed my image to alpine:3.7 from alpine:python image. I have fixed many errors except installing psycopg2. While installing psycopg2 with pip, error is coming:

```
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:28:0:
    ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    
    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
    
    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
```

I have tried many things, read all questions related to this problem. But none of them works on me.

The content of Dockerfiles is

```
FROM alpine:3.7
MAINTAINER Test

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools

ENV PACKAGES="\
    dumb-init \
    musl \
    libc6-compat \
    linux-headers \
    build-base \
    bash \
    git \
    ca-certificates \
    freetype \
    libgfortran \
    libgcc \
    libstdc++ \
    openblas \
    tcl \
    tk \
    libssl1.0 \
    psycopg2-binary \
"

ENV PYTHON_PACKAGES="\
    numpy \
    matplotlib \
    scipy \
    scikit-learn \
    pandas \
    nltk \
"

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
      gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client
RUN apk add --virtual build-dependencies python3 --update py-pip \
RUN apk add --virtual build-runtime build-base build-essential postgresql-devel libpq-dev python3.8-dev libpython3.8-dev openblas-dev freetype-dev pkgconfig gfortran \
RUN ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h \
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip \
RUN pip3 install $PYTHON_PACKAGES \
RUN apk del build-runtime \
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies $PACKAGES \
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp-build-deps

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app
RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

The content of requirements.txt file is

```
Django>=3.1.5,<3.2.5
djangorestframework>=3.12.2,<3.13.0
psycopg2>=2.8.5,<2.9.5
djangorestframework_simplejwt
django-cors-headers
requests
djangorestframework-datatables
django-filter

flake8<3.8.4,<3.9.0
```

Comment: Just use python slim image, alpine it's a bad choice (for python, not in general)

Comment: [article to read](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have changed image to python-slim. Now all of the machine learning packages, Django and database are properly working. :) And it is working faster than alpine image as you propose.

Answer (score 0):

In Alpine you need to `install python3-dev` and `musl-dev`.